# i have a routine that saves specified sheets in a workbook to a pdf doc but if i make some of the sheets charts my routine falls over

Tags: vba, excel

The list of sheets is specified in the names range "SaveList", which takes some as worksheets and some as charts (full page ones) but it falls over with

> run-time error 13 "type mismatch"

**Routine code below**

```
Sub SaveFile()
'Recalc Sheets prior to saving down

A = MsgBox("Do you want to Save the Performance Reports?", vbOKCancel)
If A = 2 Then Exit Sub

Dim SaveSheets As Variant
Dim strFilename As String
Dim sheetListRange As Range
Dim sheetName As Variant
Dim wksheet As Variant

Dim wkbSrc As Workbook
Dim wkbNew As Workbook
Dim wksNew As Worksheet
Dim wksSrc As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim v As Variant
Dim Jimmy As Variant

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
strFilename = Worksheets("Control").Range("SavePath").Value & "Ergonomie_Consultants_Performance_" & Format$(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ""
v = strFilename

Set sheetListRange = Worksheets("Control").Range("SaveList")
Set wkbSrc = ActiveWorkbook
Set wkbNew = Workbooks.Add
i = 0

For Each sheetName In sheetListRange
    If sheetName = "" Then GoTo NEXT_SHEET
    For Each wksheet In wkbSrc.Sheets
        If wksheet.Name = sheetName Then
            i = i + 1
            wksheet.Copy Before:=wkbNew.Sheets(i)
            Set wksNew = ActiveSheet
            With wksNew
                .Cells.Select
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            End With
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
            GoTo NEXT_SHEET
        End If
    Next wksheet
NEXT_SHEET:
Next sheetName

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'dont need the default new sheets created by created a new workbook
wkbNew.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=v, FileFormat:=xlNormal

If VarType(v) <> vbString Then Exit Sub

If Dir(v) <> "" Then
    If MsgBox("File already exists - do you wish to overwrite it?", vbYesNo, "File Exists") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
End If

With ActiveWorkbook
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=v, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=3, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With

'  ActiveWorkbook.Close
' EMAIL  Attachment File
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "waverley.inc@gmail.com"
    '        .CC = ""
    '        .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Report" & Format$(Now(), "_YYYYMMDD")
    .Body = "DRAFT PLEASE REVIEW :Consultant Report" & Format$(Now(), "_YYYYMMDD")
    .Attachments.Add v & ".pdf"
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

'If there is an unknown runtime error give the user the error number and associated description
'(Description is already set if the erorr is G_LNG_CRITICAL_ERROR)
If Err.Number <> CRITICAL_ERROR Then Err.Description = "Run-time error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

Err.Description = "Error saving worksheet as file: " & Err.Description
Err.Source = "Error saving worksheet as file: " & Err.Source
'Raise the error up to the error handler above
Err.Raise Number:=CRITICAL_ERROR


End Sub
```

Comment: What line is it throwing the error ? or should we guess ?

Comment: ok thx, its actually copies the first chart (whole page) then falls over the next page with the type mismatch

Comment: Can you direct me to what line ?

Comment: Set wksNew = ActiveSheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the section of code below instead of your 2 x `For Each` loops.

using `Application.Match` to find if the `Sheet.Name` is found within `sheetListRange` array (values read from Named Range "SaveList").

```
Dim sheetListRange As Variant

' instead of saving the Range, save the values inside the Range in an Array
sheetListRange = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Control").Range("SaveList"))

Set wkbSrc = ActiveWorkbook
Set wkbNew = Workbooks.Add

i = wkbNew.Sheets.Count
For Each wksheet In wkbSrc.Sheets
    ' instead of 2 X loops, use Application.Match
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(wksheet.Name, sheetListRange, 0)) Then ' worksheet match in "SaveList" Named Range
        wksheet.Copy Before:=wkbNew.Sheets(i)

        If Not wksheet.CodeName Like "Chart*" Then ' if current sheet is not type Chart
            Set wksNew = ActiveSheet
            With wksNew
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            End With
        End If
        i = i + 1
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
    End If
Next wksheet
```

Comment: falls over here: Set wksNew = wksheet.Copy(Before:=wkbNew.Sheets(i))

Comment: `Set wksNew` (where `wksNew` is declared as a `Worksheet`), and the `.Cells.Copy`, isn't going to work if the wksheet is a `Chart`.  (The title of the question includes the phrase "but if i make some of the sheets charts my routine falls over".)

Comment: @YowE3K thanks for clearing it up, I'll modify later. need to make lunch ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado - I've just finished dinner, but still feeling hungry - maybe I'll visit you and steal your food.

Comment: falls over here as it seems to loop over the first name in the SaveList range and it copies the same chart

Comment: Set wksNew = ActiveSheet

Comment: any further ideas guys? maybe its the easter eggs hahaha

Comment: @AndyDonaldson try edited code to support sheet types Chart

Comment: Yes indeed txvm